# Getting desired row using CASE when encountering duplicates

Tags: mysql

I understand that when using CASE, it will select the first value that it can fulfill.  However, I'd like to get a specific value first if there's a duplicate and if not, then choose the other.

For example, if my table looks like this:

```
date      email        ordered
1/1/17    email_1      N
3/1/17    email_1      Y
1/1/17    email_2      Y
1/1/17    email_3      N
```

and what I want is this:

```
date      email        ordered
3/1/17    email_1      Y
1/1/17    email_2      Y
1/1/17    email_3      N
```

My current query looks something like the below but it doesn't work as `CASE` is giving me `'N'` for `email_1` due to finding it first.

> CASE WHEN ordered = 'Y' THEN ordered ELSE 'N' END

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired results you can use aggregation with string function to pick single value from the aggregated result set.

```
select
substring_index(group_concat(`date` order by ordered desc),',',1) `date`,
email,
substring_index(group_concat(`ordered` order by ordered desc),',',1) `ordered`
from demo
group by email
```

> From your post i assume you want to pick single record for each email and priority will be given to ordered = 'Y'.

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a60f0/2)